# Pgadmin4 on kubernetes: saving users and settings in a volume

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgadmin-4, persistent-volumes

I want to save users accounts and other settings in a volume for a pgadmin4 k8s instance, I did that:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: pgadmin
      namespace: pgadmin
    spec:
      selector:
       matchLabels:
        app: pgadmin
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: pgadmin
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: pgadmin4
              image: dpage/pgadmin4
              env:
               - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
                 value: "admin@example.com"
               - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
                 value: "mysecpwd"
               - name: PGADMIN_PORT
                 value: "80"
              ports:
                - containerPort: 80
                  name: pgadminport
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /
                  name: pgadmin-storage

          volumes:
               - name: pgadmin-storage
                 persistentVolumeClaim:
                   claimName: pgadmin-pv-claim
    ---
        kind: PersistentVolume
        apiVersion: v1
        metadata:
          name: pgadmin-pv-volume
          namespace: pgadmin
          labels:
            type: local
            app: pgadmin
        spec:
          storageClassName: manual
          capacity:
            storage: 5Gi
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
          hostPath:
            path: "/mnt/data"
    ---
        kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
        apiVersion: v1
        metadata:
          name: pgadmin-pv-claim
          namespace: pgadmin
          labels:
            app: pgadmin
        spec:
          storageClassName: manual
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 5Gi
```

The problem is when I restart the pod the created users disappears even if the pv is bounded to the pod, I'm not sure about this section:

```
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /
                  name: pgadmin-storage
```

I think I have to specify the directory where the user's information and settings are saved, I tried the default directory `/pgadmin4` but the pod crashes.

Comment: Have you followed any kind of guide in order to achieve the current state of your use case?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no, I just create a deployment to use the pv claimed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on @Wytrzymały answer, I checked the deployment created with helm, and I found that the correct `mountPath` is `/var/lib/pgadmin`, the section should be like so:

```
      ...
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
          name: pgadmin-storage
      ...
```

another thing is that I had to change owner of that directory so the application can write to it, I used `InitContainers` for that (pgadmin uid = 5050):

```
...
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: volume-mount-hack
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 5050:5050 /var/lib/pgadmin"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: pgadmin-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
....
```

hope this can help somebody

Answer (score 2):

I suggest installing pgAdmin with [this helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/cetic/pgadmin). With it you will be able to **Configure the way how to persistent data:**

> - Disable: The data does not survive the termination of a pod.
> - Persistent Volume Claim(default): A default StorageClass is needed in the Kubernetes cluster to dynamic provision the volumes. Specify
>   another StorageClass in the storageClass or set existingClaim if you
>   have already existing persistent volumes to use.

Also, there are some configurable parameters of the pgAdmin chart that can be adjusted in order to configurate you persistance options:

> - `persistence.enabled`:  Enable the data persistence or not
> - `persistence.existingClaim`:    Provide an existing PersistentVolumeClaim, the value is evaluated as a template
> - `persistence.storageClass`: PVC Storage Class for PostgreSQL volume
> - `persistence.accessMode`:   The access mode of the volume
> - `persistence.size`: The size of the volume

Comment: your answer helped me to find the cause of the problem